How do I specify a container image in GitHub actions using a secret?
Setting the "container" image below is not allowed, but I would rather not hard code it.
  build-web:

    needs: login-ecr
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    env:
      AWS_ECR_REPOSITORY: ${{ secrets.AWS_ECR_REPOSITORY }}

    container:
      image: ${{ secrets.AWS_ECR_REPOSITORY }}

Github's container documentation does not speak to it, that I can tell.

This is covered under Context availability:




Workflow key
Context
Special functions




jobs.<job_id>.container.image
github, needs, strategy, matrix, vars, inputs
None




So, if you don't want to hardcode, you could use the vars context, or pass in a secret from another job via needs.
